# JS in indesign. autotag error

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to apply tags to all the EPS files in the document.
My code:

```
 #target indesign
var allItems=app.activeDocument.pageItems.everyItem().getElements().slice(0);
for(var i=0;i<allItems.length;i++)
    { 
        var allInnerItems = allItems[i].allPageItems;
        for(var j=0;j<allInnerItems.length;i++)
        {
            (allInnerItems[j].toString() == "[object EPS]") ? 
                allInnerItems[j].parent.autoTag() : alert('false');
        }
    }
```

The code finds all EPS and applies to their Rectangle objects AutoTag method. But I was given the error: "The object or the parent story is already tagged or cannot be taged". Besides if i choose some rectangle object with EPS and click the function "AutoTag" in user interface, it will work.
Maybe somebody knows, what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for what you are trying to do.

In the inner loop you forgot to change `i++` to `j++`.

Also, you don't have to get the string value of an object to test against it (ie. `.toString() == "[object EPS]"`), you can just ask for its `constructor`.

Finally, if you don't want any more errors for elements that are already tagged, you can add a condition to your `if` statement that tests whether or not the `pageItem` has an `associatedXMLElement` before attempting to `autoTag()` it.

```
var allItems = app.activeDocument.pageItems.everyItem().getElements();
for(var i=0; i<allItems.length; i++)
{ 
   var allInnerItems = allItems[i].allPageItems;
   for(var j=0;j<allInnerItems.length; j++)
   {
      var item = allInnerItems[j];
      if (item.constructor == EPS && !item.parent.associatedXMLElement) {
         item.parent.autoTag()
      } else {
         alert('false');
      }
   }
}
```